# How to change "Read more" button text on Wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, button, translation, updates

After updating plugins, my "Read more" button on posts changed it's name. In Latvian language it was "Lasīt vairāk", while in Russian "Читать дальше". It's just in plain English. The image of how it looks now is via this [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/NZFah1Bus7djyXkT6). Plugin updates basically wiped out the padding and the name of the button.

Tried modifying functions.php with

```
// Replaces the excerpt "Read More" text by a link
function modify_read_more_link() {
return '<a class="read-article" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read 
More Link Text</a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );

// Replaces the excerpt "Read More" text by a link
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
return '<a class="read-article" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> 
Read the full article...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Tried loco translate and modifying internal translations of Elementor-related plugins. The closest I could get is that the elements is named "eael-post-elements-readmore-btn". Styling the element with CSS doesn't do anything. Padding or margin do not work. It's locked. Can anyone provide a hint?

The button should be in Latvian and Russian language, not in English.

PS. Figured that it is Elementor posts plugin related overriding functions.php and translators as well. At this moment, can't figure how to CSS this thing. Stays static.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in **functions.php**:

`function develop_custom_excerpt_more($more) {
     global $post;
     // edit here if you like
     return '...  <a class="excerpt-read-more" href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="'. __( 'Read ', 'domain_name' ) . esc_attr( get_the_title( $post->ID ) ).'">'. __( 'Show more &raquo;', 'domain_name' ) .'</a>';
 }
 add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'develop_custom_excerpt_more' );`

Comment: Thank you so much, you save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured that it is Elementor posts plugin related overriding functions.php and translators as well. The eael-post-elements-readmore-btn was not changing in padding nor in margin because line-height which by default is set to 1 could not allow space for expansion.